# Bootstrap 3: how do I change the width of 'a' tag exactly like the width of image it contains?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I change the width of the <a> tag below exactly as the test_small.jpg image width?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-5">
   <a class="fancybox thumbnail" href="/assets/images/gallery/test.jpg">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="test_small.jpg">
   </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-7">
   ...
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried using:

```
<a class="fancybox thumbnail" style="width: auto" href="/assets/images/gallery/test.jpg">
```

without success.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** http://www.bootply.com/PGsq7xJeOt

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle please?

Comment: Here we go: http://www.bootply.com/PGsq7xJeOt. All of the answer so far don't solve the issue...

Answer (score 1):

You could just add an auto width. You will need to specify `display: block` for this to take effect.

```
.fancybox.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd add class to that a .. for example: .customThumbnail

HTML:

```
<a class="fancybox thumbnail customThumbnail" href="/assets/images/gallery/test.jpg">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="test_small.jpg">
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a.customThumbnail {display: block; width: 200px;}
```

You can use any width here (within col-md-5), since your image is responsive - it will adjust.
Also, try resetting padding (as the "a" might have some padding around it).

```
a.customThumbnail {display: block; width: 200px; padding: 0}
```

Although, a JSFiddle would be the best :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an active example on [ToWho](http://towho.org/).

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-5">
    <a href="/assets/images/gallery/test.jpg">
    <div class="content"> <!-- This div isn't necessary, but is helpful for organizing -->
    <img class="img-responsive" src="test_small.jpg" alt="Small Images">
    </div>
    </a>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-7"></div>
</div>
```

Why it's not working is hard to solve without a fiddle. The anchor shouldn't need anything special to make it take up the space of the div, especially since it's in a Bootstrap grid element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a new class giving it width:100% or make it an inline style.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <a href="/assets/images/gallery/test.jpg"> <img class="image-responsive" style="width:100%;"   src="test_small.jpg"/></a>   </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```